# Analysing a signal in Matlab with Excel data set

Tags: excel, matlab, signal-processing

I have a set of data in excel like this:

[image: excel data]

column A is time in ns and column B is the electric field strength.
now I want to convert the time-domain signal from these data to a frequency-domain signal with DSP toolbox in matlab.

to calculate Fs (sampling frequency) in order to use in signal analyse i use this formula:

```
time = T(:,1);      
L=2033;       
Ts = mean(diff(time));
Fs = 1/Ts;
```

which leads to :

```
Fs= 5e+09
```

then I import the signal (E) with sampling frequency Fs in signal analyze toolbox.
my signal is like this:

[image: Signal in Matlab]

now i want to apply a bandpass filter in 16-32 MHZ range , so :

[image: Out of memory]

I've increased the paging file to maximum on my system with no success!
I should say that my system configuration is like this:

i5 CPU at 2.5 GHz

8 GB R3 Ram at 1600 MHz

**I have two specific question:**

**1- what should I do? Is there any thing that I should do to to be able to design the filter on my system?**

**2- if I change the time to second and the frequency to hz , how much does the results change?**

Comment: 64bit bit matlab? otherwise only ~3gb ram are used

Comment: That is a _very_ high sample rate.  I'm guessing the filter order it came up with is absurdly large (it's hiding under the error box).  Can you tell us?

Comment: I suggest migrating this question to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/.  You may have better luck there.

Comment: @DanielR thanks.. yes, it 64 bit matlab

Comment: @chappjc thank you.... filter order is 50.

Comment: Oh, I see.  That's not bad.  Your pass band is reasonable w.r.t. the sample rate, I think. Sorry... maybe try manually doing this with `remez` and `filter` to see if the GUI is doing something weird.